# Passing NSOpenPanel options to NSDocument

Tags: macos, cocoa

I know how to add an AccessoryView to an NSOpenPanel (and that works correctly).

Now I would like to make the options that the user selects in the AccessoryView available to the document that is opened.

Any suggestions how that can be doen (if at all?)

Comment: What is the question, how to get the options from the accessory view or how to pass the options to the document? Please add your code to the question.

Comment: I can read the options just fine, no problems there. But how I get the options to the document?  I don't see how I can pass them onto the document to be opened. (There is no code as this is not a code question)

Comment: How and when do you add the accessory view?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a standard solution, so I created my own:

- Introduced a dictionary in the NSDocumentController that associates file URLs with option sets
- Override the runModalOpenPanel and wrap the runModalOpenPanel of super with first the setup of the accessory view, and afterwards the evaluation of the options and adding of the options to the dictionary for the associated urls.
- When a document is opened, the document can -through the shared NSDocumentController- access the dictionary and retrieve the options.

I am not blown away by this solution, but I also do not see an easier path.

Example code:

```
struct OptionsAtFileOpen {
    let alsoLoadFormat: Bool
}

class DocumentController: NSDocumentController {

    var fileOptions: Dictionary<URL, OptionsAtFileOpen> = [:]

    var accessoryViewController: OpenPanelAccessoryViewController!

    override func runModalOpenPanel(_ openPanel: NSOpenPanel, forTypes types: [String]?) -> Int {

        // Load accessory view
        let accessoryViewController = OpenPanelAccessoryViewController(nibName: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "OpenPanelAccessoryView"), bundle: nil)

        // Add accessory view and make sure it is shown
        openPanel.accessoryView = accessoryViewController.view
        openPanel.isAccessoryViewDisclosed = true

        // Run the dialog
        let result = super.runModalOpenPanel(openPanel, forTypes: types)

        // If not cancelled, add the files to open to the fileOptions dictionary
        if result == 1 {

            // Return the state of the checkbox that selects the loading of the formatting file
            let alsoLoadFormat = accessoryViewController.alsoLoadFormatFile.state == NSControl.StateValue.on

            for url in openPanel.urls {
                fileOptions[url] = OptionsAtFileOpen(alsoLoadFormat: alsoLoadFormat)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

And then in Document

```
override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {
    ...
    if let fileUrl = fileURL {
        if let dc = (NSDocumentController.shared as? DocumentController) {
            if let loadFormat = dc.fileOptions[fileUrl]?.alsoLoadFormat {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```